# Select2 jquery plugin show number of selected items in the result instead of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using **Select2 jQuery Plugin**.

https://select2.github.io/ for reference

When I am using the multiple dropdown option. The result of selected items is shown as tags in a box but, I just want to show the number of items selected.

Is it possible with **Select2 jQuery plugin**

**HTML**

```
<select multiple style="width:100%">
  <option value="1">Name1</option>
  <option value="2">Name2</option>
  <option value="3">Name3</option>
  <option value="4">Name4</option>
  <option value="5">Name5</option>
  <option value="6">Name6</option>
  <option value="7">Name7</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('select').select2();
```

I want output as below

[image]

instead of tag like output.

**[Example working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/402ejhoy/)**

Comment: How do you gonna deselect elements, it you can't see them?

Comment: @ Justinas 3. If you open the list and click on a selected item it deselects it.

Comment: @Justinas -  @ 8odoros is right

Comment: Try bootstrap select picker https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: I guess something simple like that is not what you want https://jsfiddle.net/402ejhoy/1/

Comment: @8odoros count is fine. but i dont want tags that selected I want only count

Answer (score 15):

You can add this code after initializing select2

```
$('select').on('select2:close', function (evt) {
        var uldiv = $(this).siblings('span.select2').find('ul')
        var count = $(this).select2('data').length
        if(count==0){
          uldiv.html("")
        }
        else{
          uldiv.html("<li>"+count+" items selected</li>")
        }
```

Ref: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m16j1ebq/1/)
Reference to select2 events: [Here](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events)

Edit:
 If you want to display a blank when user deselects everything,
Use this fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m16j1ebq/2/)

Edit: 
 Updated to remove flaw in deselection of data and changed it to main answer.
Fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m16j1ebq/4/)

Comment: There is an issue in this code. If you select something and click again in the top box it says "0 items selected" while keeping the selections.

Comment: @8odoros It's working fine is the jsfiddle.. It says 0 items selected because there are zero items selected.. Clicking on the same item again deselects it.. Shouldn't the user get to deselect selections?

Comment: @8odoros edited the answer and included a fiddle to clear the field if all items are deselected

Comment: Still not working correctly. Check this: Click an item (box says "1 item selected"). Click on the box (opens the list, highlights the selected item). Now, click again on the box (now says "0 items selected") but still if you click again the list opens and highlights the chosen item.

Comment: it is removing search `input`. I don't want it on `close` event because I am going to use `closeOnSelect:false`

Comment: @8odoros Got you.. did a little googling and chnaged the fiddle accordingly.

Comment: @murli2308 You can use other select2 events as stated in the docs.. link to the doc is provided in the answer

Comment: @PrasunJajodia and what about 'search input'. it is getting deleted

Comment: @murli2308 Could you clarify what 'search input' means? If you're saying that the selectbox is losing its values on submit, I checked in the fiddle, and it's still retaining selected values

Comment: @PrasunJajodia https://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/402ejhoy/ see example. we have a search `input` field to search options

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118617/discussion-between-murli2308-and-prasun-jajodia).

Answer (score 5):

Selectors can certainly be improved, but as a blueprint, adding a counter element on change and hiding the tags like this seems to work as asked.

```js
$('select').select2({closeOnSelect: false}).on("change", function(e) {
  $('.select2-selection__rendered li:not(.select2-search--inline)').hide();
  $('.counter').remove();
  var counter = $(".select2-selection__choice").length;
  $('.select2-selection__rendered').after('<div style="line-height: 28px; padding: 5px;" class="counter">'+counter+' selected</div>');
});
```

```css
.counter{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:5px;
 }
 .select2-search--inline{
   background-color:Gainsboro;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select multiple style="width:100%" id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Name1</option>
  <option value="2">Name2</option>
  <option value="3">Name3</option>
  <option value="4">Name4</option>
  <option value="5">Name5</option>
  <option value="6">Name6</option>
  <option value="7">Name7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: search `input` field is getting removed.

Comment: you are showing count which is fine. But it is removing `input` field of search which I don't want

Comment: This is updating every select2s on page.

Answer (score 1):

although the answer is given.

you can try this code. first initialize than on close call it.

```
   jQuery('.multi-select-pbwp').select2();
    $('.multi-select-pbwp').on('select2:close', function() {
        const $select = $(this);
        const numSelected = $select.select2('data').length;

        $select.next('span.select2').find('ul').html(function() {
            return `<li class="class="select2-selection__choice">${numSelected} selected</li>`;
        })
    });
```