# HTML Select Box showing the number of items selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement where I have to create a multi selection select box. On selecting multiple items, the select box shows the number of items selected.

For example, if I have created a "Languages known" select box as below and selected 3 options, it should appear as below:

[image]

Is there any existing framework by which I can achieve this?

I have searched on the internet but cannot get proper examples for this.

Comment: Funny thing is that both this and duplicated use "3 items selected" in their example :)

Comment: @Salketer haha thats funny I just noticed it!! 
I posted the issue i am facing in the above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652325/select2-jquery-plugin-show-number-of-selected-items-in-the-result-instead-of-tag/46051206#46051206) where the question is already answered!

Comment: see my comment on it, this is absolutely the wrong way to get help. As I said, you are asking how to do this, so it is exactly answered over there. Now, if you are still facing problem, try to ask "select2 input does not show number of selected items as expected" or something close to that, with what you tried.